# Random behavior in Android Studio

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I'm working in an app using Parse.com and I've been experiencing some random behavior, I made a simpler version of my code to show you and while it keeps being random (the results I expect happen about 4 in 5 times) it got better (in my code it's correct about 2/5 of the runs).

So the method is this, a very simple creation and filling of a new object:

```
public void test(){

final List<ParseObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(j=0;j<4;j++){
    list.add(new ParseObject("Object"));
    list.get(j).put("Column1", "sup");
    list.get(j).put("Column2", "bro");

    if(j==3){

        ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(list, new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NANANANANANANANA BATMAN!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
}
```

Problem is it creates 4 ParseObjects (as it should) only 4/5 of the tries, then 1/4  it's only 3. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create and store your `ParseObject` in a variable and then, use `put("Column1", "sup");` and `put("Column2", "bro");` on it before adding this variable directly to your list? because you are accessing your list two times for nothing where it can be avoided.

It would be cleaner and it would allow you to debug better.

Comment: Well thanks, I guess it's better that way but I still don't understand what's failling. It seems to be a bug because I can't make any sense out of it.

Comment: If you adapted the code as I said, use the step by step feature of the debugger and check the value of your variables, it will help you a lot. Sadly its all I can do for help with the code you provided. Good luck!